# Dynamically building HTML code using jquery and ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I need to dynamically build HTML code using jquery in ASP.NET. After generating HTML I should get page like this:

[image]

Each field can be clicked and than I got extra options like in the picture. I've managed to do this using ASP.NET code-behind, but I know that it is a bad practice to build HTML on server side. Now I'm trying to build it on client side, but I have some problem that I can not detect.

This is my script for generating HTML and invoking code behind method using ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetTeamMembers() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "team-members.aspx/LoadTeamMembers",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(data) {
        var htmlCode;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.lenght; i++) {
        htmlCode += "<div class=\"heading\" id=\"" + data.d[i].TeamMemberID + "\"><span>" + data.d[i].Name + "</span><i>+</i></div><div class=\"details\"><ul class=\"form\"><li>" +
                           "<label>Name:</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"tmname\" class=\"in-text\" /></li><li><label>Hours per week:</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"in-text\" />" +
                           "</li></ul><ul class=\"form\"><li><label>Username:</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"in-text\" /></li><li><label>Email:</label>" +
                           "<input type=\"text\" class=\"in-text\" /></li></ul><ul class=\"form last\"><li><label>Status:</label><span class=\"radio\">" +
                           "<label for=\"inactive\">Inactive:</label><input type=\"radio\" value=\"1\" name=\"status\" id=\"Radio5\" /></span>" +
                           "<span class=\"radio\"><label for=\"active\">Active:</label><input type=\"radio\" value=\"2\" name=\"status\" id=\"Radio6\" /></span>" +
                           "</li><li><label>Role:</label><span class=\"radio\"><label for=\"admin\">Admin:</label><input type=\"radio\" value=\"1\" name=\"status\" id=\"Radio7\" />" +
                           "</span><span class=\"radio\"><label for=\"worker\">Worker:</label><input type=\"radio\" value=\"2\" name=\"status\" id=\"Radio8\" />" +
                           "</span></li></ul><div class=\"buttons\"><div class=\"inner\"><a href=\"javascript:;\" id=\"updateMember\" class=\"btn green\">Save</a>" +
                           " <a href=\"javascript:;\" id=\"deleteMember\" class=\"btn red\">Delete</a> <a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"btn orange\">Reset Password</a>" +
                           "</div></div></div> ";
        }
        $('#listMembersDiv').html(htmlCode);
        console.log(htmlCode);
    }
    function OnError(data) {
        console.log(Error);
    }
</script>
```

This is method on the code behind page:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<SmallTeamMember> LoadTeamMembers()
{
    List<SmallTeamMember> allTeamMembers = new List<SmallTeamMember>();
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PRACTICE-001;Initial Catalog=n.mosorinski;User ID=n.mosorinski;Password=n.mosorinski;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
    SqlDataAdapter sqla = new SqlDataAdapter();
    string getTeamMembers = "select TeamMemberID, Name from TeamMember";
    sqla.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(getTeamMembers, Conn);
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqla);
    Conn.Open();
    DataTable teamMembersData = new DataTable();
    sqla.Fill(teamMembersData);
    allTeamMembers = (from DataRow row in teamMembersData.Rows select new SmallTeamMember { TeamMemberID = Convert.ToInt32(row["TeamMemberID"]), Name = row["Name"].ToString() }).ToList();
    Conn.Close();
    return allTeamMembers;
}
```

This is simple model SmallTeamMember, type I'm returning in list:

```
public class SmallTeamMember
    {
        public int TeamMemberID { get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }
```

And this is div element I'm using for generated code:

```
<div id="listMembersDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

I invoke my JS funciton on page load, have all information in data variable in this format during debugging:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"VegaTimeSheetProject.SmallTeamMember","TeamMemberID":23,"Name":"Sanja Bajic"},{"__type":"VegaTimeSheetProject.SmallTeamMember","TeamMemberID":24,"Name":"Marija Aleksic"},{"__type":"VegaTimeSheetProject.SmallTeamMember","TeamMemberID":25,"Name":"Srdjan Milenkovic"},{"__type":"VegaTimeSheetProject.SmallTeamMember","TeamMemberID":26,"Name":"Nemanja Mosorinski"}]}
```

But after all is done I get undefined value for htmlCode variable and empty HTML page. Does someone sees what I'm doing wrong in jquery part? This is my fifth day learning jquery and JS so I'm not that good with it yet and I don't have enough knowledge to fix this potential error.

Comment: You should initialize `var htmlCode = "";` before adding new content.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < data.d.lenght; i++)  ???

Comment: @metadingsYou were right. Initialization var helped.
Now clicking and opening fields don't work. I only have list of names. Gonna have to checked generated HTML better :) Thanks. :)

Comment: @AfterGlow Yep that was the main problem - me don't know how to type... I've misspelled length word... Thanks for noticing, helped me a lot! :)

Comment: To generate html code, I suggest you to use html template to make things nicer, like mustache.